# Can't update/save featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a site that for some reason I can't seem to save a featured image to the post.  When I set the featured image, it pulls it in fine - however when I hit "save" then the image disappears.  Does anyone know what might be causing this or what I can do to fix it?

Thanks! Having a crappy friday so if I could fix this it would make my day.

Comment: Pull the site down to a local installation so you don't mess with a live site.  Deactivate all your plugins and switch to a default theme (2012/2013/2014).  Reactivate your theme and plugins one by one to determine which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Hmm, what's weird is that it's actually "advanced custom fields" that's causing the issue.  I really need that plugin so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Might be worth asking them for support then

Comment: I never found ACF with these issues, because it's nicely coded one. Have you tried disabling other plugins that can conflict with ACF? And you can also try `example.com/wp-admin/update-core.php` and hit **Re-install Now** button to reinstall WordPress to fix any WP bug